# Paperclip - allow only PDF

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

How can allow to use upload only some kind of files, for example only PDF, Word or Excel files?
I use **Paperclip** gem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `content_type` validation, like here:

```
validates_attachment :avatar, :content_type => { :content_type => "application/pdf" }
```

Comment: should be `validates_attachment_content_type` (for Rails 3.2)